# Active menu but in secon lvl wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, menu

Please see my attachment for a better understanding of what I mean.

I have a portfolio tab on a page that when clicked now becomes "active". But on the "portfolio" tab I also have Filter 1, Filter 2, Filter 3, etc. If I click on any of the filters, the link is OK (www.domain.com/portfolio/filter), but the "portfolio" tab loses the "active" class ...

Currently, I have such a code calling the menu in header:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location' => 'menu-glowne',
'container' => 'ul',
'menu_class'=> 'navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto',
'menu_id' => 'menu-top'
 )); ?>
```

The code by calling the menu in a single page

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location' => 'menu-realizacje',
'container' => 'ul',
'menu_class'=> 'navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto',
'menu_id' => 'menu-top','menu-realizacje'
) ); ?>
```

The code that I have in functions.php that generates an active menu

```
<?php add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){ $classes[] = 'active nohover';}
return $classes;
}
?>
```

Attachment:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVO96.jpg)

Thanks for help. Regards, Simon